# Create dictionary of statistics for several lists in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I would like to create some basic statistics for several lists of data and store them in a dictionary:

```
>>> from statistics import mean,median
>>> a,b,c=[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
```

The following list comprehension works and outputs stats for "a":

```
>>> [eval("{}({})".format(op,a)) for op in ['mean','median','min','max']]
[2, 2, 1, 3]
```

Assigning the list's variable name (a) to another object (dta) and evaluating "dta" in a list comprehension also works:

```
>>> dta="a"
>>> [eval("{}({})".format(op,eval("dta"))) for op in ['mean','median','min','max']]
[2, 2, 1, 3]
```

But when I try to tie this all together in a dictionary comprehension, it does not work:

```
>>> {k:[eval("{}({})".format(op,eval("k"))) for op in ['mean','median','min','max']] for k in ['a','b','c']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

My guess is that the eval is processed before the comprehension, which is why 'k' is not yet defined? Any suggestions for how to get this work or a different routine that would accomplish the same output?

Comment: Interesting question, but your code works: `{'a': [2.0, 2, 1, 3], 'c': [8.0, 8, 7, 9], 'b': [5.0, 5, 4, 6]}`

Comment: Why are you using eval ?

Comment: Why do you use `eval` here? Python has first-class functions: use them! `[stat(a) for stat in [mean, median, min, max]]` (for example).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! Thank you: `{k:[op(eval(k)) for op in [mean,median,min,max]] for k in ['a','b','c']}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not quote the `k` in the inner `eval`:

```
{k:[eval("{}({})".format(op,eval(k))) for op in ['mean','median','min','max']] for k in ['a','b','c']}
                                 ^
```

Or drop `eval` altogether:

```
[[mean(k), median(k), min(k), max(k)] for k in [a, b, c]]
```

You can do a simple workaround with the keys to change this to a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Right. Even better to go without any `eval`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotation marks around k in your call to eval in the format function.

I ran the following commands:

```
> from statistics import mean,median
> a,b,c=[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
> {k:[eval("{}({})".format(op,eval(k))) for op in ['mean','median','min','max']] for k in ['a','b','c']}
```

and got the following output:

```
{'a': [2.0, 2, 1, 3], 'c': [8.0, 8, 7, 9], 'b': [5.0, 5, 4, 6]}
```